# Error RROR [08001] [IBM] SQL30081N when connecting to AS400 (iSeries) from NHibernate using C#

Tags: c#, database, nhibernate, ibm-midrange

I have absolutely no experience with AS400 DB2 so please forgive any glaring mistakes as I am learning as I go along. I have 2 boxes I can connect to running **v5r3** or **v4r3.**  and I am using **NHibernate 3**. However, when I try and connect I keep getting the following exception :-

```
ERROR [08001] [IBM] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. 
Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  
Location where the error was detected: "192.168.1.11".  Communication function detecting the error: "connect".  Protocol specific error code(s): "10061", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001
```

Below is my NHibernate configuration file:-

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.DB2400Dialect</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.DB2Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.connection_string">Server=192.168.1.11;Database=TESTDB;UID=XXX;PWD=XXX;          </property>
        <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
        <property name="command_timeout">15000</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread_static</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I am not sure if this is because the versions of AS400 are too early? my nhibernate configuration is incorrect? or I have something set up incorrectly on the AS400 itself.

Any advice would be most appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Are you able to connect to this instance of DB2 with other tools? *By the error*, looks like it something with the database.

Comment: I am able to connect and query using the Client Access ODBC driver through Excel. However, I want to be able to read / write to my database so not sure that the ODBC driver will allow me to do this. Could it be something to do with my configuration of the database in WRKRDBDIRE?

Comment: What driver are you using with NHibernate?

Comment: I am using the IBM DB2.Net Data provider which is on this path on my current development machine (C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\bin\netf20\IBM.Data.DB2.dll)

Comment: @lostinwpf I updated my answer with more information about **DDM** connections.

Comment: @JamesA, thanks so much for your help I feel I am making some progress now. I think that I now connect to the server but now get the error message {"ERROR [58016] [IBM] SQL30072N \"0x11DC\" Parameter is not supported. SQLSTATE=58016\r\n"} not sure where to go from here and don't want to fill the comments section up. If I try and connect to the box running v5r3 I get ERROR [42968] [IBM] SQL8002N  An attempt to connect to a host failed due to a missing DB2 Connect product or invalid license. **Do I need to get this license to get this to work?**

Comment: You will need a license for DB2 Connect.  The IBM i Net.Data driver is available with the Client Access/IBM Access product licensed with the host system.  You can install it from the hosts **/QIBM/ProdData/Access/Windows/Install/Image** directory.  Feel free to PM me if you need more help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two types of database connections available on the IBM i - **DRDA** and **DDM**.  **DRDA** is used for native connections (DB2.Net.iSeries) and **DDM** is used for DB/2 LUW (DB2.Net, DB/2 Connect) connections.

### DRDA

Verify the database host server running:

```
WRKACTJOB SBS(QSERVER) JOB(QZDASRVSD)
```

Check the port status:

`NETSTAT OPTION(*CNN)`, hit <kbd>F2</kbd> and verify ports 449, 8470, 8471 and 8476 are in state **Listen**.

Start the database host server with the command:

```
STRHOSTSVR SERVER(*DATABASE)
```

### DDM

Verify the ddm tcp server is running:

```
WRKACTJOB SBS(QSYSWRK) JOB(QRWTLSTN)
```

Check the port status:

NETSTAT *CNN, hit <kbd>F2</kbd> and verify port 446 is in state **Listen**.

Start the ddm tcp server with the command:

```
STRTCPSVR SERVER(*DDM)
```

Include the ddm port number in your connection string:

```
Server=192.168.1.11:446;Database=TESTDB;UID=XXX;PWD=XXX;
```

---

This IBM Redbook should provide more information:

[Integrating DB2 Universal Database for iSeries with Microsoft ADO .NET](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg246440.html)

Comment: If I put this commandSTRHOSTSVR SERVER(*DATABASE) 
>> Host server daemon jobs unable to communicate using IPX and the first command gives the status as SELW.

Comment: @lostinwpf That message is just a warning.  `SELW` means the job is waiting for connections.  Are you still getting the SQL30081N on connect?

Comment: yes I am still getting SQL30081N. Could it be related to the database name / configuration? These are purely guesses on my part.

Comment: @lostinwpf You should never need to change the database name or configuration in a normal environment.  That is only used for hosting multiple database engines or clustering servers.

Comment: All those ports (449,8470,8471,8476) are in a state of Listen

Answer (score 2):

The real underlying error is this one:

*TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it*

So apparently the end point is not listening, or there is some firewall blocking you, or you mistake the address. If there is something to configure in the as/400 to enable that TCP address to listen for connection, maybe is not properly enabled.